# How can I use ROW_NUMBER() to count only distinct values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    sg.rolesID, 
    count# = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sg.rolesContainerID),
    sg.rolesContainerID,
    eventTimeStamp AS timeStarted, 
    eventTimeStamp AS timeFinished
FROM 
    view_SecurityGroup sg 
WHERE 
    sg.rolesID = '22400ab8-62a2-4a69-b002-5dd4d0459728'
ORDER BY 
    sg.rolesContainerID, timeStarted, timeFinished DESC
```

With these results:

```
rolesID                                 count#      rolesContainerID                        timeStarted                     timeFinished        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     1          153F36C8-6FB5-4B50-A2D7-000209C96663    2023-02-27 14:26:50.583         2023-02-27 14:26:50.583     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     2          153F36C8-6FB5-4B50-A2D7-000209C96663    2023-02-27 14:26:50.587         2023-02-27 14:26:50.587     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     3          153F36C8-6FB5-4B50-A2D7-000209C96663    2023-02-27 14:26:58.420         2023-02-27 14:26:58.420     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     4          790E699D-1BDE-4CCA-B6A6-013696B81774    2023-02-28 15:41:02.540         2023-02-28 15:41:02.540     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     5          790E699D-1BDE-4CCA-B6A6-013696B81774    2023-02-28 15:42:51.540         2023-02-28 15:42:51.540     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     6          790E699D-1BDE-4CCA-B6A6-013696B81774    2023-02-28 15:44:27.560         2023-02-28 15:44:27.560     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     7          223C4704-2B04-404D-991A-04B408C6CA93    2022-11-04 13:59:03.343         2022-11-04 13:59:03.343     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     8          223C4704-2B04-404D-991A-04B408C6CA93    2022-11-04 13:59:03.347         2022-11-04 13:59:03.347     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     9          223C4704-2B04-404D-991A-04B408C6CA93    2022-11-04 14:05:49.133         2022-11-04 14:05:49.133     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     10         229105A8-2713-44FE-B0D0-0FF09F54E905    2023-02-27 00:28:58.840         2023-02-27 00:28:58.840     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     11         229105A8-2713-44FE-B0D0-0FF09F54E905    2023-02-27 00:29:48.513         2023-02-27 00:29:48.513
```

But I want the `count#` to only be incremented for each rolesContainerID...like this:

```
rolesID                                 count#      rolesContainerID                        timeStarted                     timeFinished        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     1          153F36C8-6FB5-4B50-A2D7-000209C96663    2023-02-27 14:26:50.583         2023-02-27 14:26:50.583     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     1          153F36C8-6FB5-4B50-A2D7-000209C96663    2023-02-27 14:26:50.587         2023-02-27 14:26:50.587     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     1          153F36C8-6FB5-4B50-A2D7-000209C96663    2023-02-27 14:26:58.420         2023-02-27 14:26:58.420     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     2          790E699D-1BDE-4CCA-B6A6-013696B81774    2023-02-28 15:41:02.540         2023-02-28 15:41:02.540     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     2          790E699D-1BDE-4CCA-B6A6-013696B81774    2023-02-28 15:42:51.540         2023-02-28 15:42:51.540     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     2          790E699D-1BDE-4CCA-B6A6-013696B81774    2023-02-28 15:44:27.560         2023-02-28 15:44:27.560     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     3          223C4704-2B04-404D-991A-04B408C6CA93    2022-11-04 13:59:03.343         2022-11-04 13:59:03.343     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     3          223C4704-2B04-404D-991A-04B408C6CA93    2022-11-04 13:59:03.347         2022-11-04 13:59:03.347     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     3          223C4704-2B04-404D-991A-04B408C6CA93    2022-11-04 14:05:49.133         2022-11-04 14:05:49.133     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     4          229105A8-2713-44FE-B0D0-0FF09F54E905    2023-02-27 00:28:58.840         2023-02-27 00:28:58.840     
22400AB8-62A2-4A69-B002-5DD4D0459728     4          229105A8-2713-44FE-B0D0-0FF09F54E905    2023-02-27 00:29:48.513         2023-02-27 00:29:48.513
```

Is there a way to do that in SQL Server?

Thanks!

Comment: Dense rank exists

Comment: [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @CoderGautamYT sorry, I didn't know there was that.  Thanks!  I will delete this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 count# = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sg.rolesContainerID),
```

or

```
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sg.rolesContainerID) AS count#,
```

Answer (score 0):

Hogan's answer is correct, that would work perfectly.

I just thought it might be interesting for you to see this query extracted from [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-four-ranking-functions-used-in-the-same-query).

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName  
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.PostalCode) AS "Row Number"  
    ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.PostalCode) AS Rank  
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.PostalCode) AS "Dense Rank"  
    ,NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY a.PostalCode) AS Quartile  
    ,s.SalesYTD  
    ,a.PostalCode  
FROM Sales.SalesPerson AS s   
    INNER JOIN Person.Person AS p   
        ON s.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID  
    INNER JOIN Person.Address AS a   
        ON a.AddressID = p.BusinessEntityID  
WHERE TerritoryID IS NOT NULL AND SalesYTD <> 0;
```

| FirstName | LastName | Row Number | Rank | Dense Rank | Quartile | SalesYTD | PostalCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | Blythe | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3763178.1787 | 98027 |
| Linda | Mitchell | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4251368.5497 | 98027 |
| Jillian | Carson | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3189418.3662 | 98027 |
| Garrett | Vargas | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1453719.4653 | 98027 |
| Tsvi | Reiter | 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2315185.6110 | 98027 |
| Pamela | Ansman-Wolfe | 6 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1352577.1325 | 98027 |
| Shu | Ito | 7 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 2458535.6169 | 98055 |
| José | Saraiva | 8 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 2604540.7172 | 98055 |
| David | Campbell | 9 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 1573012.9383 | 98055 |
| Tete | Mensa-Annan | 10 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 1576562.1966 | 98055 |
| Lynn | Tsoflias | 11 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 1421810.9242 | 98055 |
| Rachel | Valdez | 12 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 1827066.7118 | 98055 |
| Jae | Pak | 13 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 4116871.2277 | 98055 |
| Ranjit | Varkey Chudukatil | 14 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 3121616.3202 | 98055 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ty4GmFbU)

In the example they show how different ranking window function work using all of them in the same query, so you can clearly see and understand the difference between all of them.